# SQLAlchemy jsonb column - How to perform filter based on list of ids on a key

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, jsonb

I have a list of ids like:

```
tracker_ids = [69]
```

I need to get all the APInformation objects based on the tracker_id.

data looks like this:

```
{ 'tracker_id' : 69, 'cpu_core_avg': 89.890', 'is_threshold': true,'datetime':1539053379040 }
{ 'tracker_id' : 70, 'cpu_core_avg': 65.0', 'is_threshold': false, 'datetime':1539053379040 }
{ 'tracker_id' : 69, 'cpu_core_avg': 34.9', 'is_threshold': false,'datetime':1539053379040 }
```

I tried the following but it raises an error.

```
session.query(APInformation).\
    filter(APInformation.data['tracker_id'].in_(tracker_ids),
           APInformation.data['datetime'].astext.cast(BigInteger) > 1539053379040).\
    all()
```

the error it throws:

```
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) operator does not exist: jsonb = integer
LINE 3: ...oring_apinfomation".data -> 'tracker_id') IN (69)
                                                                ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: What is the error?  Have you tried testing with echo=True on your `engine` to see if there is a syntax error in the sql?

Comment: @IljaEveriläI don't know how to do for an array? can you help me with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must cast the jsonb value before using it with the IN predicate, as you had done with the *datetime* value:

```
session.query(APInformation).\
    filter(APInformation.data['tracker_id'].astext.cast(Integer).in_(tracker_ids),
           APInformation.data['datetime'].astext.cast(BigInteger) > 1539053379040).\
    all()
```

Comment: Is it possible to do aggregation on JSON values?

Comment: It is possible.